# Blink matching brackets when doing terminal input, like CLISP does?

Tags: c++, c, ruby, input, readline

If you type `}` after `{`, `)` after `(` or `]` after `[` in [CLISP](http://www.clisp.org/) (and I'm sure many more) terminal, the corresponding opening bracket gets highlighted for about a second, before returning to normal state.

How can I get this behavior, at least when doing `gets` in Ruby, `cin` in C++ and `scanf` in C?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: do you want the *shell* to match the parenthesis? Do you want the editor when programming those languages to match parenthesis? Or do you want your own program in one of those languages to match parenthesis?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I just want to highlight the brackets when I'm asking for an input from the shell in one of these languages.

Comment: When you are doing input in your own program, you are **not** interacting with the shell, but the terminal. That is probably what confused me. The answer for C and C++ is that you cannot do that directly, you will need to control input at a lower level than `scanf` or  `std::cin`. Consider looking into the ncurses or equivalent libraries.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, right, changed "shell" to "terminal".

Answer (score 0):

To control things like cursor position, text formatting and so on, you have to talk directly to the terminal, in a way which is not accessible through the stream interfaces of `cin` of `scanf`. Not sure about Ruby, but I'd guess the same applies there as well. On POSIX systems, this control is achieved via a set of I/O controls ([`ioctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl)), which provide an out-of-band communication with the terminal device. There are libraries which provide some degree of portability when talking to a terminal. The most commonly used is probably [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/), which was already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744025/blink-matching-brackets-when-doing-terminal-input-bash-zsh-like-clisp-does#comment18886119_13744025) by David Rodríguez.